# Workflow of the VueJS project

Tags: vue.js, render

I don't know how this vuejs project render data to the web browser. Can anyone help me to explain this?
Link url: https://github.com/huytrongnguyen/vue-cms 
Notice: you have to clone this project to your computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour, have a look around, and read through the help center, in particular How do I ask a good question - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. As you can see one important note there is "Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague". No one will deploy your project on their computer and debug the issue for you. Please clarify what is the problem in concise way with all the information needed for answering inside the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

Vue loader in [the webpack config](https://github.com/huytrongnguyen/vue-cms/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L14) will change all of the components into Javascript. That JS is loaded when the `index.html` in the dist folder is opened in a browser. After the javascript is parsed, it'll run and populate the DOM with HTML strings created by the webpack process

Comment: No, i just want to know the order of rendering data that when open file **index.html** they will show content from the root instance **#app** -> **index.js** and then... Can you help me to explain this?

Comment: regular HTML I'd say, from top to bottom. Whatever is included next will render next. E.g. a route component, then the component in there, etc etc. Is that what you want to know?

Comment: Thank for your answer